# What is the easiest way for Jenkins to perform an action on recieving an email?

Tags: ruby, email, jenkins

I need a way to have Jenkins perform an action on receiving an email.  I plan on sending an email with a Ruby script and net/smtp.

Comment: Why email? What do you want Jenkins to do? I'm not aware of email receiving plugins, but you can use the Jenkins REST API to perform various actions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: I need to test a set of servers is up and running and that they can all send and receive email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not aware of a plugin for Jenkins to start jobs via email. However, it is easy to use a service like [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com) (which converts the incoming email to an HTTP POST) and use a small script of your own to make this interact with the Jenkins API and schedule jobs.

I've done this personally and it works pretty well. I didn't make full use of the API and just used the following URL:

```
http://SERVER_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build?delay=60
```

You don't need the delay but I found it useful to ask multiple jobs to be set at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that lets you send commands to Jenkins via email. Haven't personally used it, but here it is:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Commander+Plugin